# Toggle Show HTML Nodelist elements with custom attribute

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

I have an anchor elements with a custom attribute called `"attachment_rename_link_no"` (with the value being equal to a number) like so:

`var attachment_rename_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("a[attachment_rename_link_no]")`

The node list is appearing properly, however, when I do `attachment_rename_buttons[0].style.display = 'none'`, it doesn't hide the element.

Is there a special way to hide/show the display of nodelist elements?

UPDATE: Code works as expected

Comment: There's no special way to change the display property of your elements outside of what you have. I would check to see what the query selector is returning, and then see what the first array element looks like.

Comment: I ran your code and it works as expected. Maybe there is something else you're not showing us that is making this not work.

Comment: I mocked up an example: http://jsfiddle.net/s708p2nw/ and can't duplicate the issue. Please show your code if you are having trouble, and list any errors you get.

Comment: The code was indeed working as expected, I just didn't see it visually on the page working as properly. sorry.